# ¿Cómo lanzar analytics con una función de js?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Debo lanzar el script de
**Google Analytics** desde una función de *javascript*.

**Tengo el siguiente código**

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-8"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-8', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
  </script>
```

¿Cómo puedo escribir el código dentro de una función?

Ya que tal cual o sin la etiqueta script no funciona.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, se puede saber porque necesitas lanzarlo con una función? Que estás tratando de hacer?

Comment: Cargar Google Analytics solo cuando se aceptan cookies

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421083/insertar-cdn-al-ejecutar-funci%c3%b3n-javascript/421088#421088), te permite agregar un nuevo script, con la posibilidad de ejecutar una función cuando se haya completado la carga.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
//función para añadir un tag <script> dentro de <head>
function addScript(src) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', src);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

//función que añade el script para google analytics con un ID dado
// y la configuración por defecto
function addGoogleAnalytics(id) {
  addScript(`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${id}`);
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.gtag = function () {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  };
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', id, { 'anonymize_ip': true });
}

...

if (cookiesAccepted) {
  addGoogleAnaytics('UA-1234567-8');
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, muy interesante, creo que está muy bien. Una pregunta, què finalidad tiene el script en head?

Comment: Cargarse antes de cualquier otra cosa.

Comment: Gracias Pablo. No me carga las cookies. Me funciona sustituyendo el primer script por:
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-8"></script>
pero no entiendo porqué. Se te ocurre algo?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que podría ser algo como:

```
function nombreDeLaFuncion(){
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-8', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
}
```

Comment: Gracias, Y la parte del primer script? (la primera línea en la consulta)