# Cargar etiqueta script al hacer click en un botón

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero cargar una etiqueta  cuando hago click en un botón. Actualmente hice lo siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="prueba-content"></div>
    <script class="scriptload" src=""></script>
</div>
```

Por lo tanto yo tengo un icono que al hacer click le digo que me rellene el campo src

```
$('div.search a.icon-lupa').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    $('.scriptload').attr('src','https://prueba.com/iframe.js');
    $('div.buscador-modal').css('display','flex');
});
```

Pero claro logicamente esto no me funciona xk no me está cargando el iframe que yo necesito, alguna idea?

Gracias!

Comment: para que cargar un `script` luego si igual lo vas utilizar? no seria mejora cargarlo normalmente como todo 
y cuando se requiera simplemente ejecutar su funcionalidad?

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/421088/54039) seguramente te puede ser útil.