# alternativas con document.write

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Recientemente estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto web, y se me has solicitado buscar una alternativa con el uso del document.write, ya que este considerado como mala practica y afecta al rendimiento de la página, este es utilizado dentro de un archivo js de la siguiente manera:

```
document.write('<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/parallax.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.countTo.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/pace.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/additional-methods.min.js"></script>');
```

Esto funciona a través de un archivo llamado main.js el que es llamado después por el archivo html.

Comment: ¿Por qué usan el document write para añadir plugins y no añadirlos directamente en el HTML, disculpa? Además, le falta más contexto a tu pregunta.

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/421083/54039), parecer ser lo mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
// Creamos un nuevo script y lo agregamos al documento
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js';
document.body.append(script);

// Verificamos que se haya creado
console.log([...document.body.querySelectorAll('script[src]')]);
```

Comment: Y como se aplicaría para cada uno de los plugins? ya que debo llamarlos a todos, como sería con este método para cada uno?

Comment: @user224276, esa ya es otra pregunta, pero con un poco de imaginación podes resolverlo. Por ejemplo, creas un arreglo con los links, luego iteras el arreglo para agregar cada uno. Opciones hay varias...

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: @user224276, intenta resolver tu problema, si no podes, podes crear una nueva pregunta. De los errores también se aprende.