# ¿como puedo exportar funciones entre archivos js?

Tags: javascript

```
//archivo animales.js
import * as datos from './medicamento.js'
datos.prueba()


// archivo medicamento.js
export function prueba() {
    console.log('ok')
}
```

me sale este error ReferenceError: require is not defined en la consola solo quiero exportar la funcion
prueba hacia otro archivo js que lo estoy usando en una pagina web.

Comment: Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/421088/54039) pueda servirte si lo que quieres es cargar un script adicional en el navegador.

Comment: En los navegadores, por el momento solo se puede hacer `import` en los tags `<script>` con el atributo `type="module"` o usando `import()` como función.

Comment: @Emeeus nada "Se bloqueó la carga de un módulo de" dice

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo lo hago yo. Lo mio está aplicado a clases, pero el funcionamiento es el mismo:

```
// archivo core.js
import {Rectangulo} from "./_modules/app.js";



//archivo app.js
export class Rectangulo{

    constructor(alto, ancho){
        this.alto   = alto;
        this.ancho  = ancho;
    }

    getArea(){
        console.log(this.ancho*this.alto);
    }

    printDescription(){
        console.log(`Soy un rectangulo de ${this.alto} por ${this.ancho}`);
    }
}
```

Verás que en el core, utilizo el `from` con una ruta concreta, eso es porque al ser `core.js` el que carga el módulo, es este mismo documento el que tiene que apuntar al otro, no desde el `html` (quizá esto suene muy tonto, pero a mi me lía mucho el tema de las rutas).

Al hacer el `export` en el archivo del `app.js` verás que lo pongo al principio antes de declarar la clase. Pero el mismo resultado hubiera sido al poner al final export {Rectangulo}